# How to choose unique visitors(users) for a certain day?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I can take unique users for all days, but if I enter a certain day, then I get an empty array.

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->leftJoin('a.event', 'e')
        ->leftJoin('a.customer', 'c')
        ->select('count(date_format(a.date, \'%Y %m %d\'))')
        ->where('e.id = :id')
        ->andWhere('a.page = :page')
        ->andWhere('c.status = :customer')
        ->setParameter('id', $event)
        ->setParameter('page', $page)
        ->setParameter('customer', $customer)
        ->groupBy('c.id')
        ->having('count(distinct date_format(a.date, \'%Y %m %d\')) > 1');

    if ($date != '') {
        $query = $query
            ->andWhere('date_format(a.date, \'%m/%d/%Y\') = :date')
            ->setParameter('date', $date);
    }
    $query = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: you should really provide more data about how the records in your database look like, what the relations are, maybe a sample dataset on sqlfiddle and the expected result and such. you make it really hard to get to the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 0):

from symfony debugger you find the runnable query (under doctrine) that you can use to run in your database client directly and see if you have anything missing like may be date format or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

don't know what "a" is in your query, but let's say it collects participation to your event:

```
customer | event | date
 A       |  1    | 2020-06-17
 A       |  1    | 2020-06-18
 B       |  1    | 2020-06-18
```

now you set `$date` to 2020-06-17. your `andWhere` clause then will remove the records with other dates:

```
 A       |  1    | 2020-06-17
```

now the query is grouped (due to original query), and the `having(count(distinct date) > 1)` (simplified) filters out the last remaining row.

this is obviously under the assumptions, that the table has the semantics I assume

so you probably want some other logic in your `having` (maybe >0) or only use that when `$date` is not set or whatever.